# Create new variable x by selecting the value of a cell in a row conditional on the variable name containing the value of a variable z

Tags: stata

I have a dataset of individuals. Each individual is observed across different years and countries. I have two independent variables `x2002` and `x2010` (see Dataex example: Before). These contain the values of a variable X for each year for a specific country. For example, all individuals observed in 2002 in France have a value of 10 for `x2002` and a value of 200 for `x2002`. I want to create a new variable called `X`. For each row, the value for `X` should be set to the cell of the variable that contains the equivalent year in the variable name. (My original dataset has variables from `x2002` to `x2018` and 100.000 observations, so I need to automate this.). I am relatively new to Stata, The result should look like this:

Dataex example: After

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input int id str6 country int(year y1) float(y2 x2002 x2010 x)
7 "France" 2002 7 1.8628873 10 200  10
5 "France" 2002 2  19.52281 10 200  10
6 "France" 2010 7  14.80233 15 500 500
8 "France" 2010 9 15.173367 15 500 500
3 "USA"    2002 8 2.2806208  5 100   5
1 "USA"    2002 6 18.706757  5 100   5
4 "USA"    2010 4  7.421789 30  25  25
2 "USA"    2010 4  9.642876 30  25  25
end
```

Dataex example: Before

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input int id str6 country int(year y1) float(y2 x2002 x2010)
7 "France" 2002 7 1.8628873 10 200
5 "France" 2002 2  19.52281 10 200
6 "France" 2010 7  14.80233 15 500
8 "France" 2010 9 15.173367 15 500
3 "USA"    2002 8 2.2806208  5 100
1 "USA"    2002 6 18.706757  5 100
4 "USA"    2010 4  7.421789 30  25
2 "USA"    2010 4  9.642876 30  25
end
```

My code looks like this:

```
foreach i in year {
    gen x = list x`i' in i
}
```

I do not understand how to dynamically select a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input int id str6 country int(year y1) float(y2 x2002 x2010)
7 "France" 2002 7 1.8628873 10 200
5 "France" 2002 2  19.52281 10 200
6 "France" 2010 7  14.80233 15 500
8 "France" 2010 9 15.173367 15 500
3 "USA"    2002 8 2.2806208  5 100
1 "USA"    2002 6 18.706757  5 100
4 "USA"    2010 4  7.421789 30  25
2 "USA"    2010 4  9.642876 30  25
end

gen X = . 

quietly forval y = 2002/2018 { 
   capture replace X = x`y' if year == `y' 
}
```

This is quite concisely done in Stata, but here hinges on substitution of the contents of a local macro both as part of a variable name and as the value of a variable.

Note that `foreach i in year` is legal, but not at all a loop over the distinct values of `year`. It's a loop over one item, the name or text `"year"`. Also you need different syntax for referring to the local macro inside the loop, as just given.

EDIT

To use a previous year (I am not sure how this relates to the data example, but it is a question in comments) you could go

```
gen X = . 

quietly forval y = 2002/2018 { 
    local z = `y' - 1 
    capture replace X = x`z' if year == `y'
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Nick Cox. I did not know the forval loop, thank you! :)

Comment: Is there also a way replace X with the y-1? I have tried 
````gen Z = . 
quietly forval y = 2002/2018 {
 capture tempvar z 
 capture generate `z'= `y'-1
  capture replace Z = x`z' if year == `y' 
}
````